# motorola droid turbo battery not charging

Tags: charging, motorola-droid

I bought droid turbo about five months and I upgraded it to marshmallow. Unfortunately, it fell on the ground four times, then the fourth time it stopped charging. When I connect the charger, it sshows charger is connected but in the battery performance section, "it says not charging".

Answer (score 0):

This had happened with my Nexus 6. As a workaroud I used to align the USB cable at an angle with the charging port. The solution however was to get the charging port repaired or replaced which stopped this problem.

I have unfortunately no information as to why it shows connected, but  not charging.